# Model classes in liferay 6.1

Tags: model, liferay-6

Where can i find the "com.liferay.portlet.blogs.model.BlogsEntry" . I am not able to find the this path in liferay. 
Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 1):

- If you need to use the class in your portlet code.
  You'll need to access the [Your liferay Server]/tomcatXYZ/lib/ext/portal-service.jar.
- If you need to study or debug the class you'll need to download the source. Visit the [download section](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases) and go for the 'portal source'. You can import it as a project in eclipse for more convenience. It's useful to have the portal trunk handy, anyway

Comment: But they are all class files. I want java files for the same.

Comment: It is a *very* bad idea to include `portal-service.jar` into your portlet's lib folder. Better, just add `portal-service.jar` to the build path of your project or, if you're working with Maven, add the JAR as a *provided* dependency to your POM.

Comment: +1, it's not a good solution, definitely not the best. That's why I said "one way", not "the best way". I've deleted that part, since it not a good advice, but it looks like that the op didn't search for the jar anyway

Answer (score 0):

Download Lifera 6.1 source and import portal-trunk project in eclipse.In eclipse click ctrl+shift+r and write the class BlogsEntry.Then it will automatically show BlogsEntry class in com.liferay.portlet.blogs.model package

Answer (score 0):

You can find all classes linked to this model (Liferay version 6.1.2-ga3) here :
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.1.2-ga3/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portlet/blogs/model